# How does one prove that DEC does not parameterize DEC?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

The $n$th slice of a set $A \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$ is defined as:

$$A_n = \{x \in \Sigma^{*}\mid\langle n,x\rangle \in A\}$$

The definition of parameterization is as follows -
$C$ parameterizes $D$ (also called $C$ is universal for $D$) if,

$$\exists A \in C \quad\text{s.t}\quad D = \{A_n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

However, I have no idea how to prove that the class of decidable languages (DEC) can parameterize DEC.

Comment: What are $A_n$ here? And what is $A$ used for?

Comment: @nirshahar A is a finite sequence of strings. I have updated the question with the definition of An above.

Comment: Thanks. How is $\langle n,x \rangle$ defined here? Are we working with binary alphabet (i.e, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$) and $n$ is interpreted as a binary number?

Comment: @nirshahar n is a natural number. So to determine if a string is in A_n, we stick the number n in front of it and check it is in A.

Comment: But some natural numbers may not even be a part of your alphabet! This would make a syntactically problematic question here. If $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, then what is $5a$ here? It is not part of $\Sigma^*$, since $5\notin \Sigma$...

Answer (score 2):

Okay first you need to know that there exists a numbering $\phi$ for all the Turing-Machines that is $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to TM$ is a computable surjection. This is often called [discription number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_number).
Now we define:
$$
A = \{\langle p,w \rangle | \text{ the TM } \phi(p) \text{ accepts } w\}
$$
This language is decidable since $\phi$ is computable and using the Universal TM we can simulate $\phi(p)$ on $w$. Thus $A \in DEC$.
But now
$$
\{A_n|\, n\in \mathbb{N}\} = DEC
$$
because for every TM $B$ there exists a $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi(n)$ is an encoding of $B$. Hence $A_n$ is the language decided by $B$.